# How to resize element inside jumbotron class

Tags: html, css

I need to have small font-size for an unorder list that is inside jumbotron div class. I tried to style it with Css, but none works.

This is the code that need to be smaller:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Informazioni di debug del servizio deployato:</h3>
    <hr>
    <h4><ul style="list-style-type:disc">
        <li><a href="">ID: {{ processDefinition.id }}</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Name: {{ processDefinition.name }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Deployment ID: {{ processDefinition.deploymentId }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Category: {{ processDefinition.category }}</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">URL: {{ processDefinition.url }}</a></li>
    </ul></h4>
    <hr>
</div>
```

EDIT: Yes i know  is an error i forget to delete it and is here only because i do many edit and try before post here :)

PS: But why -2 votes?

Comment: try this `ul li{
  font-size:10px;
}`

Comment: Not enough information provided, what did you try? Set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for help!

@Senthe More information for what? I try other solution (like h4) before ask here, but how this can be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that the entire list `<ul>` is in the header `<h4>`.  Try adding it separately, because the default list is assigned according to the size of the text header `<h4>`, and add the css properties for `ul` element:

```
ul li {
font-size: 12px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your mistakes:**

1. You cannot have `<ul>` inside a `<hX>` tag.
2. For the `list-style-type: disc` to be visible, you need to add `margin-left` to the `<li>` or `padding-left` to the `<ul>`.
3. For getting a smaller size, use `font-size: 0.75em` or something similar:

**Corrected Code:**

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h3>Informazioni di debug del servizio deployato:</h3>
  <hr>
  <ul style="list-style-type: disc; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 0.75em;">
    <li><a href="">ID: {{ processDefinition.id }}</a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Name: {{ processDefinition.name }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Deployment ID: {{ processDefinition.deploymentId }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Category: {{ processDefinition.category }}</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">URL: {{ processDefinition.url }}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

1) I know it was be only a try that forget to delete
2) disc style is already visible
3) doesnt work :(

Comment: sorry i dont yet resolved my problem

EDIT: Solved but with solution of Dmitry. Thanks Anyway!

Comment: mmm sorry i try your solution first, and adding  <ul style="... font-size: 0.75em;"> doesnt worked :(, but thanks for the tips anyway ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do on this way:

```
.jumbotron h3 hr h4 ul li a{
 font-size: 0.1rem
 }
```

Or adding a class on the jumbotron to change onlye the font-size:

```
<div class="jumbotron small-text">
<h3>Informazioni di debug del servizio deployato:</h3>
<hr>
<h4><ul style="list-style-type:disc">
    <li><a href="">ID: {{ processDefinition.id }}</a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Name: {{ processDefinition.name }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Deployment ID: {{ processDefinition.deploymentId }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Category: {{ processDefinition.category }}</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">URL: {{ processDefinition.url }}</a></li>
</ul></h4>
<hr>
```

```
.small-text h3 hr h4 ul li a{
 font-size: 0.1rem
 }
```

or

```
.small-text{
 font-size: 0.1rem !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Solved with Dmitry solution. Your solution work and is useful too :D